# Craft Commerce: Sub total before tax in cart?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm looking to get the sub total of all items in the car before and tax is added on. The example shop code doesn't seem to have this implemented. Is it possible to do?

```
  Total Discount: {{ cart.totalDiscount|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Total Shipping: {{ cart.totalShippingCost|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Total Tax: {{ cart.totalTax|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Total Tax (inc): {{ cart.totalTaxIncluded|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Item Total: {{ cart.itemTotal|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Base Discount: {{ cart.baseDiscount|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
  Base Shipping Cost: {{ cart.baseShippingCost|currency(cart.currency) }}<br>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [Commerce 1.1.1212](https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1212), `cart.itemSubtotalWithSale` is deprecated.

Use `{{ cart.itemSubtotal|currency(cart.currency) }}` instead.

<strike>`{{ cart.itemSubtotalWithSale|currency(cart.currency) }}`</strike>